# throws java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Im trying to fetch data from my server with Android 8 (26 Oreo) and I get the following error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
    at 
okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:398)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:46)
    at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
    at 
retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:291)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:430)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:287)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:350)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:179)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader.read(ResponseBody.java:252)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1287)
    at 
  com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1325)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:482)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)
    at 
  com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read
 (Reflecti veTypeAdapterFactory.java:214)
     at 
 retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert
  (GsonResponseBodyConve rter.java:37)
    at 
 retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert
(GsonResponseBodyConve rter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at 
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at 
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Im using Retrofit 2.3.0 and OkHttp 3.9.0. The strange thing is that this error only happens on API 26 Oreo and not on any previous APIs, I get this error randomly, sometimes yes, sometimes not.

Comment: Did you find the issue to this? having the same trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this `@Header("Connection","close")` on your retrofit call. It has resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in emulator, try it in your mobile. This works for me.